# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 with angular9.1.6

Tags: angular, typescript

> I am using angular9.1.6 ,but i check every i declared in my
>   application, I donot know where i make mistake and i am gettin below
>   type of error when i compile my application.
>   [> ERROR in src/app/service/httpclient.service.ts:13:29 - error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'User'.
>
> 13  return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/users');][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9yjI.png)
>   src/app/admin/users/users.component.ts:3:10 - error TS2724: Module
>   '"../../service/httpclient.service"' has no exported member
>   'HttpClientService'.  Did you mean 'HttpclientService'?
>
> 3 import { HttpClientService } from
>   '../../service/httpclient.service';
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/service/httpclient.service.ts:7:14
>       7 export class HttpclientService {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       'HttpclientService' is declared here.

When I inspect it on chrome web browser in console I am getting this:

> type of error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 (Not Found)
>   **:1 Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> **:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './admin/users/users.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> httpclient.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpclientService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  getUsers()
{
 return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/users');
}
}
```

> Usercomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../model/User';
import { HttpClientService } from '../../service/httpclient.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
     users: Array<User>

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.httpClientService.getUsers().subscribe(
              response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response),
            );
  }
  handleSuccessfulResponse(response) {
        this.users = response;
      }

}
```

> User.ts

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;  
    password: string;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update class/file `httpclient.service.ts` to include an import for interface `User` (`User.ts`):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from 'relative/path/to/user.ts';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpclientService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/users');
  }
}
```

The issue is that `getUsers()` references interface `User` but you did not import interface `User` in that file.

Update:

Assuming you updated `httpclient.service.ts` with the expected import of `User`, the other issue is in `Usercomponent.ts`. The casing of the import of `HttpClientService` is incorrect, with the "c" in "Client" being the wrong casing. You are exporting it from `httpclient.service.ts` as `HttpclientService` with a lowercase "c", but you import it incorrectly with a capital "C". Change `Usercomponent.ts` with the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../model/User';
import { HttpclientService } from '../../service/httpclient.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
     users: Array<User>

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpclientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.httpClientService.getUsers().subscribe(
              response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response),
            );
  }
  handleSuccessfulResponse(response) {
        this.users = response;
      }

}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I do  in this way but still i am getting same error

Comment: @lipudalai I updated the answer with a fix for the next issue.